# What if your character is both trained in category and group of a weapon, does your character get 2 bonuses because of its proficiency when attacking?

Tags: feats, pathfinder-2e, training

I am making a dwarf barbarian character and as a barbarian he is trained in simple, martial and unarmed attack. I also choose dwarven weapon familiarity as its ancestry feat so now he is also trained in pick, warhammer and battle axe so my question is this: if I choose greatpick as my weapon does my character get both of the bonuses from my feat and class simultaneously or should I only choose one then apply it?

Answer (score 12):

### Proficiency is a bonus, which does not stack

You either have [Proficiency](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=35) with a weapon (Trained, Expert, Master, or Legendary) or you do not. You could theoretically have Proficiency twice, but it is a *type* of [Bonus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=22), and **Bonuses of the same type do not stack**. So you would only apply the higher bonus.

> Proficiency gives you a bonus that’s added when determining the following modifiers and statistics: AC, attack rolls, Perception, saving throws, skills, and the effectiveness of spells. If you’re untrained, your proficiency bonus is +0. If you’re trained, expert, master, or legendary, your proficiency bonus equals your level plus 2, 4, 6, or 8, respectively.

> There are several types of bonuses and penalties. If you have more than one bonus of the same type, you use only the highest bonus